# How do you manage your OpenCL source?

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencl

I am having a hard time deciding how I should manage my OpenCL source code so that my program can compile it at runtime.  There seem to be two many strategies.  You can create them in you C source as strings (I really don't like this approach since this seems like a horrible way to write code).  The second approach seems to be reading the .cl files at runtime using stdio and then compiling them.  This is what I have been doing.  The only issue I have with this is that it adds a dependency to my program (I would prefer it to be contained in a single executable).  Also I seem to need to run my program in the same directory as the .cl files so they can be found.  I can think of a few solutions to this but I am just wondering how you guys do it?

Finally, I just tried writing a python script which is run before compilation and generates a header file containing strings corresponding to each .cl file.  This way the cl source code can we written separately and included.  The issue I have with this is I am not sure how to handle includes within the opencl source.  How do you guys go about managing your opencl source code?

Comment: I assume that you write your code in the usual way (i.e. in an IDE with compile-checking, debugging and all the other goodness that an IDE provides) before you stringify it?

Comment: Yeah.  I use eclipse.  I then add my python script as a pre-built step.  I really like this approach but it does not help if I want to have header files in my ooencl code

Comment: So in order to have header files they need to be separate from the exe?

Comment: Well I think it needs to be a file to use the -I option in the opencl compiler.

Comment: Can you use the pre processor to compile in you .cl files at compile time with macros and #include statements?

Comment: In that case they would not be included as strings

Answer (score 4):

You could also embed the OpenCL source inside your executable. Just make a tiny script converting (perhaps with the help of [hexdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html)...) that file into a huge C file like

```
 const char myopenclsource[] = { 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x75, 
   /// etc
 };
```

<sup>(of course the OpenCL source could easily be found from the binary executable, e.g. using [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) on Linux)</sup>

Then, you'll need to change your build procedure, e.g. add a few lines to your [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

Some OpenCL implementations might also accept [SPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation) bytecode (which you might perhaps embed likewise; however, it is less easy to decode for humans, and it probably is slightly faster to load into the GPU by implementations).